# Radeon HD7870 driver crashes, AMD and XFX looking into it

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I built a new PC and my XFX Radeon 7870 isn't working so I contacted XFX support. They told me AMD and XFX are looking into it. Windows crashes after installing catalyst drivers with the error page fault in non paged area. They were pretty fast to answer but could not provide more information.

Is this likely a software problem or could it be hardware? I would hate to be told after two weeks or something that the card will never work and have to exchange it. I also wonder if it's only my card or every model. Maybe I could ask for an exchange

Comment: Have you googled around to see if others are reporting the same issue? If the manufacturers know about the issue it's probably software.

Comment: I have googled this issue for 2 days. There are people reporting similar problems and I read and tried a lot of suggestions but none worked. I hope it is software and a new driver will fix this..

Comment: If lots of others are having the issues it is either software or a systemic issue with the hardware. Either way it should be fixed by the manufacturer.

Comment: Meh I will probably have to wait weeks in order to get my system working as intended. I wonder if no working drivers is a valid reason to ask for an exchange with the shop. I'll see. Thanks for the replies.